# UL lists adjust position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a little trouble with a UL list position/resize.

I have some `<li>` tags with different height and same width and I'd like to adjust the position removing the blank space between them when you resize the window. So they will always be close top/bottom/left/right

Here is a sample that I'd like to make it work.
http://jsfiddle.net/WX6yY/

Make sense?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "So they will always be close..."? Would using the css float property do the trick?

Comment: You need JavaScript for this layout. As already suggested, use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). It's very good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this update of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/WX6yY/1/) will kinda explain you why you're having this blank space between.. To solve this kinds of issues I think you have to use some JS help, check out jQuery Masonry plugin for starters perhaps?

Comment: i'm not thirtydot :) mark as answered if you think that's going to work for you.

Comment: I'd have upvoted this answer, except I don't understand what you're trying to show with the "updated code", and you didn't link to jQuery Masonry.

Comment: @thirtydot, I added numbers to show the sequence of the boxes, so that it's clear that the bigger box in a "row", which is 3rd, is dictating the height there. Simply wanted to show how theese boxes lay out as it might not have been clear for the author with the "one" and "two" texts in.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were aiming for?

http://jsfiddle.net/WX6yY/2/

Comment: nope, he wants them all align nicely for whatever the column number is. try resizing his example down/up to see what he means.

Comment: Exactly what thirtydot said.Thanks guys.